# Browser wipes out the output on completion of the process but I want to keep it

Tags: php, flush

```
function runupdate_output($text)
{
             $text = htmlspecialchars(str_replace("\n", "\\n", $text));
             print("\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
             print("\n//<![CDATA[");
             print("\nthis.document.forms[0].pfb_output.value = \"" . $text . "\";");
             print("\n//]]>");
             print("\n</script>");
             ob_flush();
}
```

**From here I'm calling the above function**
*The runout() is being called from somewhere else on the same page.*

```
function runoutput($value)
{
    $cmd = "/root/dir/run_cmd.sh";
    $proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
    while (!feof($proc))
    {
       usleep(300000);
       $test = fread($proc, 4096);
       runupdate_output($test);
       flush();
    }
    fclose($proc);
}
```

Comment: Do you even start buffer with `ob_start`?

Comment: I want to print the live console output on the browser, so I don't want to buffer it and then print it.

Comment: You try to flush buffer that were never started...

Comment: I don't know why but without ob_flush there no effect on the browser output.